# Python os.path.join absolute path on Linux

Tags: python, linux, string, join, path-manipulation

I have a file path like this:

```
file_name = full_path + env + '/filename.txt'
```

in which:

- full_path is '/home/louis/key-files/
- env is 'prod'

=> file name is '/home/louis/key-files/prod/filename.txt'

I want to use os.path.join

```
file_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(full_path, env, '/filename.txt'))
```

But the returned result is only: `file_name = '/filename.txt'`

How can I get the expected result like above?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your last component begins with a slash, it is taken as starting from the root, so `os.path.join` just removes everything else. Try without the leading slash instead:

```
os.path.join(full_path, env, 'filename.txt')
```

Note you probably don't need abspath here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, didn't know it's that simple. Thanks :)